# onPress is working on Debug mode but not on Release mode (Flutter)

Tags: flutter

In my Flutter app, onPress is working on Debug mode but not on Release mode.

Here is my code:

```
                  onPressed: () async {
                    if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
                      SVProgressHUD.show(status: 'Please wait...');
                      await _signUpOperation();
                    } else {
                      w.wToast('Try again');
                    }
                  },
```

Comment: Your code is not showing any problem. Check for exceptions and crash reporting. Try to narrow down problem like is onPressed getting called or not. Remove all code from on pressed and just add standard snack bar or dialog and see.

Comment: I removed all code from onPressed and tried but same result. onPressed is called on debug mode and working perfectly on debug mode but in release mode it doesn't work.

Comment: Check logs and see what is logged after you press the button

Comment: Did you tried `onPress: () { print('a') }` in the debug and release Mode? If you want to point out a bug of flutter, use a clean project to make a [mwe](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Otherwise, there is nothing we can do with this piece of code.

Comment: How can I check logs in release build? Can you please show me?

Comment: Can you please paste some more code to get idea about your issue?

Comment: Sorry. Private code. Can't paste.

Comment: No problem should be in my code. Because, everything is working perfectly everytime except release apk.